# `urlSession(_:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:)` is called only once when downloading something use Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I use alamofire to realize download function. the download progress always 0,when download completed ,it becomes 1. so I debug the code, I find the SessionDelegate (followed URLSessionDownloadDelegate)’s function `urlSession(_:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:)` only called once when download completed. I don't not why,anyone can tell me?

I tried in iphoneXr(iOS 12.2)、iphoneXs（iOS 12.2）、simulator iphone7 (iOS 12.1), and all of these devices had that phenomenon. simulator iphoneX(iOS 12.2) is normal，it called the function in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the server responds with a `Content-Length` header, `URLSession` (and therefore Alamofire) is unable to calculate the progress of the download and so will only update when finished. Also, if the download is very small and is downloaded very quickly, you may not see any progress updates.